# I want to Pass the result of the QR Code from ScannerCodeActivity to the TextView in ResultWebService

Tags: android

I want to passe the result of the QR code from the ScanCodeActivity to the TextView in other layout called ResultWebService.

```
@Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        ResultWebService.resultTExtViewCode.setText(result.getText());
        onBackPressed();
    }
```

this is my ResultWebService :

```
public class ResultWebService extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static TextView resultTExtViewCode;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_web_service);

        resultTExtViewCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViw_QRcode);      
    }
}
```

How can i do this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that, but the better way is to send it in the intent as extras, or have a global variable and assign the text value of the result there.

```
Intent i=new Intent(context);
i.putExtra("QrText", result.getText());
context.startActivity(i);
```

and to get it in the other activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String qrText;

if (extras != null) {
    qrText = extras.getString("QrText");
}
// after you do the findViewById
resultTExtViewCode.setText(qrText)
```